# Joomla K2 No dropdown for "select category" in menu admin

Tags: joomla, menu, joomla2.5, joomla-k2, dropdownbox

There's a text input instead of a dropdown input in the menu admin under the administration.
When I try to create or edit a menu item and I select it's type as K2 Category, under the Basic Options section the field with label "Select Category" is a text field. Whatever I write there it doesn't affect the list of posts when I click on the menu item on the page. It lists all the posts.

Image: 
[image about the problem http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/305/theproblem.jpg](http://img713.imageshack.us/img713/305/theproblem.jpg)

[image: image about the problem]

I'm using joomla 2.5.4.

Comment: That shouldn't be appearing like that, there should be a  select box there. Have you edited any of the Joomla core files or any of the K2 files? Also, on a side note, please upgrade to Joomla 2.5.9. You are 5 versions behind!!!

Comment: As Lodder says upgrade the Joomla version. I'm not sure about k2 but several extensions only support Joomla 2.5.5 and later due to some changes made in it. Also make sure you k2 version is up to date! Then see if you have the same issues